# ASP.NET MVC: Reuse of View by two controller actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

'Add' and 'Edit' views are typically more or less identical. How can I reuse a View so that `Foos/Add` and `Foos/Edit/[Id]` both use it? What would the actions look like?

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Simply specify the view name when calling the `View()` method like

```
public ViewResult Add() {
  //...
  return View("Foo");
}

public ViewResult Edit(int id) {
  //...
  var model = repository.get(id);
  return View("Foo", model);
}
```

Your view will have to handle null/empty model values for the `Add` action or you could populate your model with default values.

Answer (score 7):

You may want to consider using an Editor Template as opposed to reusing the same View.  An Editor Template is a partial View that is used for editing and/or inserting data.

This would require separate views but the code would be minimal.  The bulk of the code would be in the template which you would reuse for both the Add and Edit actions.

After you [create your template](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html), your Add View would look like (Razor):

```
@model Models.Foo    
<h2>Add</h2>
<p>
@Html.EditorFor(model => model)  // equivalent to EditorForModel()
</p>
```

And your Edit View would look like:

```
@model Models.Foo    
<h2>Edit</h2>
<p>
@Html.EditorFor(model => model)  // equivalent to EditorForModel()
</p>
```

Comment: I favor this method too. It smells better!

Comment: I like what you're saying. However, I'm just learning MVC, and I like to learn things the long way first, then feast on the shortcuts!

Answer (score -2):

I would use jQuery ajax. Clicking on Add or Edit would call serve action which will return the same PartialView (if you want to reuse it). 
Then, in the success function of ajax call, you have just to put returned html (from that PartialView) into certain part of your page (or popup).

Nice and clean and no page reload...

Comment: This is not necessary, and in doing so the user would now need javascript enabled to run the app.